# slippy map tile zoom tool

Tags: javascript, jquery, image, image-processing, openlayers

So I've found many jquery simulated zoom tool demonstrations ([example](http://thdoan.github.io/magnify/demo.html)) where a small image and large image are stored on the server.  When the mouse pans over the small image a mapped portion of the larger image is shown in a zoom window.

The zoom feature I am hoping to employ will be used on a slippy map (openlayers,tilelite,mapnik) so it will be easier for my old eyes to see the street names.  So it is not practical to have larger versions of all the image tiles on hand for zooming.  Is it possible to actually zoom (as opposed to simulated zoom) over dynamic web page content?

I do realize I can change the font sizes in the mapnik configuration files and I will do that if there are no other options available, but I'd like to avoid that if possible.

Comment: I voted to close your question. Here is why. The official "flag" reason: *«There are either too many possible answers, or good answers would be too long for this format. Please add details to narrow the answer set or to isolate an issue that can be answered in a few paragraphs.»* **The short way to say**: *«It's a nice wish list! Can you tell us what you've tried yet to achieve at least a part of this?»* Maybe someone could help. ;)

Comment: as I said, I've tried the simulated zoom demos, but those will not work for the reasons I've stated.  I'm guessing that what I am looking to do may not be possible with the existing technologies, and I am either looking for verification of this fact or a suggestion of what methods might accomplish this task.  I think my question is quite focused.

Comment: With your added example, wich is quite cool, btw. I better understand your question. Basically You would like to have a solution that does not rely on a "bigger" image to do the magnification. Right? Still... *«too many possible answers»*.

Comment: That is correct. Could I ask you to please suggest one of your many possible solutions?

Comment: Haha... It's not that "I" am having too many possible answers. In the same paragraph, as an answerer, I focused more on the *«issue that can be answered in a few paragraphs»*.. See? Google search a bit and try to nail the question yourself. On specific coding language issues, SO community will be there. ;)